# How to drop a column's default value?

Tags: teradata

I have a table with this:

```
MyField VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC DEFAULT ''
```

I want to drop the default empty string value so that it defaults to null.  I've discovered that I can set the default value to null, but then it actually says `DEFAULT NULL` in the DDL.  This toys with the scripts I use to compare DDL diffs between multiple database environments, so I want to look simply like this:

```
MyField VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
```

**Edit:**  I am wanting this to behave the same as if I were changing a column from NOT NULL to nullable.

Non-nullable column:

```
n INTEGER NOT NULL
```

Nullable column:

```
n INTEGER
```

Notice how the latter doesn't say:

```
n INTEGER NULL
```

Comment: Maybe ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column_name DEFAULT? I do not have chance to test it.

Comment: @sidux Tried this with no success.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to apply this change in all your environments?  Isn't that why you are doing the diffs, to find differences?

Comment: @Andrew Correct.  The production column has no default value, but the dev version has an empty string.  I want dev to match production, so I want to remove the default value from the dev column.

Comment: Ooooh, ok.  In that case, I'd just make a new table in dev.  Move the data to it.  Drop and recreate the "real" table with the desired structure, and move the data into that table.

Comment: @Andrew That would work as a work-around and I hadn't thought of it, but I am really inquiring on actually dropping the default value just as I would change a column from NOT NULL to NULL without the DDL actually saying NULL in the DDL.  If no one is able to objectively answer that dropping the default value is not possible, you should provide yours as an answer and I will mark it.  I would also advise only using your approach in non-production environments as doing so would affect the CreatorName, CreateTimeStamp, and other table metadata provided that any of that is important.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop and create the column as below:

```
alter table DBC.TEST
drop MY_FIELD 


alter table DBC.TEST
ADD MY_FIELD VARCHAR(50)
```

I have tested it and its working.

Comment: I thought of that, but that would basically cause the column to move to the bottom of the column list in the DDL which would throw off my DDL comparison scripts even more.  Dropping the default value is what I am really trying to achieve.